# -UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message-

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm quite new to the discord.js programming, so please be gentle.

This is the code for my bot that should be in charge of deleting messages.

Sometimes when clearing messages, I get an error from the title of the question.

Should I use a catch block somewhere, and if so, where?

```
bot.on('message', function(message){
    if(input.startsWith(prefix + 'CLR')){
        message.delete();
            var clrcommand = input.toString().split(' ');
            if(!clrcommand[1]){
                message.channel.send({embed:{
                    title:'<clr ?',
                    description:'Error! Please specify the number of messages to clear e.g. <clr 10',
                    color:0x2471A3
            }})
            return;
        }
        if(sender.id === 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'){
            nmb=Number(clrcommand[1]);
            message.channel.bulkDelete(nmb);
        }
        else{
            message.channel.send({embed:{
                title:'<clr '+clrcommand[1],
                description:'You do not have permissions to request the deletion of messages on this server!',
                color:0x2471A3
            }})
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Since all of the methods on `message` that you are using return Promises, you should probably append `.catch()` to the end of each method operating on a message instead of trying to do a try/catch (unless you're using an async function). For example: `message.channel.send("msg").catch(err => console.log(err.stack))`. If you can use this to identify which specific line of the code is causing the error, that would be useful in solving the problem.

Comment: Managed to solve my problem by removing message.delete(); line. It was causing all kinds of problems. Thank you non the less. :)

Comment: No problem! I figured that line was causing the problem, simply given that `bulkDelete()` would be trying to delete a message that you had already deleted. Consider posting your fixed code as an answer to this question for anyone else  experiencing the same problem that may stumble onto this question in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing the `message.delete();` line, I managed to solve my problem. Thanks to @Cannicide for help.

Following is the revised code with a little addition. Maybe it helps someone. Cheers. :)

```
bot.on('message', function(message){
    if(input.startsWith(prefix + 'CLR')){
        var clrcommand = input.toString().split(' ');
        if(!clrcommand[1]){
            message.channel.send({embed:{
                title:'<clr ?',
                description:'Error! Please specify the number of messages to clear e.g. <clr 10',
                color:0x2471A3
            }})
            return;
        }
        if((clrcommand[1] < 1) || (clrcommand[1] > 99)){
            message.channel.send({embed:{
                description:'You need to enter a number between 1 and 99!',
                color:0x2471A3
            }});
        }
        if(sender.id === 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'){
            nmb=Number(clrcommand[1]);
            message.channel.bulkDelete(nmb);
        }
        else{
            message.channel.send({embed:{
                title:'<clr '+clrcommand[1],
                description:'You do not have permissions to request the deletion of messages on this server!',
                color:0x2471A3
            }})
            return;
        }
    }
});
```